# Lightmapping + custom model + manifold

Tags: unity

What are the things one should consider before doing light maps?

We have custom models in Unity Scene,while doing light mapping it stuck at "Clustering job 5/11".

After researching I come to know models should be "Manifold" to be light mapped  so we did manifold our custom models and now light maps are occurring properly though at the cost of lot of polys which is causing performance hit on Android device.

So my question is has anyone faced similar issue or workaround for same?

Comment: Have you tested it without baking the scene?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate more plz? I have deselect "Auto" in lightning window then made all the objects "Static" before baking after baking started it stuck at clustering

Comment: I meant have you tried not marking objects static, but just trying it as it is?

Comment: means without marking objects as static baked lightmap? would it will not do lightmaps on those objects?